# Routes redirect to custom location

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

When I try and access anything in my `admin/someSecureThing` I get redirected to `/`.  How can I change it so that I get redirected back to `admin/login`?

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

   /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');


    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */

        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AuthController.php you can set:

`protected $loginPath = 'admin/login';`

Please note `$loginPath` will not change where a user is bounced if they try to access a protected route. That is controlled by the App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate middleware's handle method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

If you're using a custom AuthController than it might be better to create a custom middleware.

`php artisan make:middleware AdminAuthController`

This will create a AdminAuthController.php under app\Http\Middleware folder.

Next we are going to edit the handle function as above but also make sure to:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Once that's done we need to register our new middleware under app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthController::class
    ];
```

After this all you have to do is to use `auth.admin` middleware instead of 
`auth` for any routes you want.

Your routes will look like this:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.admin'], function(){
    /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
  }

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */

        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');    
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I override the handle in my auth controller?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie No you cannot. The login part is handled in the middleware redirect()->guest('admin/login');

Comment: Hmm what else can I do as I have a custom auth controller and I am having 2x seperate logins - one will be /login

Comment: Not sure if custom middleware would be overkill but that is one option. You can create AdminAuthenticate.php and register the middleware in the Kernel.php. Instead of using auth for those routes you can use this new custom middleware.

Comment: Possibly not an overkill I am new to Laravel are you able to do me an example?

Comment: Actually it's not. That's how I use too :) I don't why I said that. Let me edit my answer with an example.